Visual Studio 2022 does not see git changes
I am using MS Visual Studio 2022 and I am facing what seems to be a recurring problem with git: the changes on a file are not detected for commit/push
The steps to reproduce are

Work with a git repository (open a solution)
Change a file
Immediatly after changing the file, the tab "Git Changes" on the right shows the changed file, but...
save the file
As soon as you save the file, the changes disappear and the file is no more seen as changed (!)

if I perform git status from the command prompt, it detects the changed file
The only way I found to see the file inside the "Git Changes" is to close Visual Studio and open it again.

After restarting VS does it work for a while and then eventually start happening again? Do you just restart VS again each time? If yes, approximately how long does it last before you have to restart VS?
